# Firefox add-on to save contents of different websites in to different locations in computer

Tags: gratis, linux, firefox

I frequently visit several websites and download documents like PDF and DOCX. The files downloaded are always saved to the downloads location. I know that I can choose "always ask" option in General tab of Preferences, to select a specific location when downloading. Or else, I can give a specific folder as the default download location.

But, is there any add-on or a feature in Firefox that can keep a memory on different locations to save the documents of different websites?

Comment: I use Download Manager by Oleksandr.  I'm not sure if that's the reason I'm able to do what you describe.  You can adjust which fields are displayed.  I added "Full Path" and it showed me the location where I had chosen to store each download.